# Special symbol in header / event title not formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, fullcalendar, utf

In FullCalendar, I can choose whether i'd like the title of events or the header title of the agenda week to be formatted correctly depending on if i save my index.php with UTF-8 or UTF-8 without BOM (equivalent to adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in `<head>`).

[image: Bad format]

How do I get both in the right format? I have tried adding meta tag, saving my index.php with different encoding but no matter the combination, one or the other is badly formatted.

Edit: Using notepad++ as text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that database content was encoded in ISO because of a ISO meta tag in the header of the webpage at a previous time.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Before the database connect call solved the problem as well as a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the header of the main webpage.